# Why is my logger's level of the logging module set to NOTSET while I have previously assigned it a level?

Tags: python, logging

I have the following file structure:

```
my_project [package]/
- main.py
- file_four.py
- python2 [package]/
  - file_one.py
  - file_two.py
  - file_three.py
```

File main.py and file_four.py are Python 3. The main.py gets called by the user, and this sets up the logger:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

class Runner():
  ..

  def run():
    subprocess.Popen(python2 file_one.py) # pseudo

def main():
  logging.basicConfig(...)

  logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
  assert logger.level == 20 # => TRUE
  Runner().run()

if __name__ == "main":
  main()
```

Now, file_one.py calls file_two.py using subprocess.Popen, subsequently file_two.py calls file_three.py and finally file_three.py calls `python3 file_four.py`. This all happens sequentially, so main.py's main() has definitely been executed before any code in file_four.py executes.

file_four.py contains the following code:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

class Four:
  def main():
    assert logger.level == 20 # => FALSE, it is 0 (NOTSET)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Four().main()
```

I thought that when you call getLogger(name) with the same name, it would always be the same. But for some reason it does not seem to work, and the level is NOTSET. Is logging something I should set per file? Because it seems like it does not transfer its attributes properly.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen(python2 file_one.py) # pseudo`

This is where your previous logging configuration is "lost". `subprocess` creates a new process that is fully independent of the parent script. Only their input/output pipes are connected, but they do not share any other resources, and most important for this question: they do not share any memory.

The logger that is created in main.py only exists in the memory of that python process. When you create a new process all its memory, including all variables and loggers are fully separate. The new process has no logging configured at all.

If you do want shared state/memory between your processes you could use the `threading` module. It will however not allow different python versions.